# Check a problem solution $au + (b + i\lambda)u_{xx} = 0$ with boundary conditions.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $a, b >0 $ and $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $\lambda \neq 0$. Consider $u \in C^{1}([\alpha, \beta])$ such that $u(\alpha) = u_{x}(\alpha) = u_{x}(\beta)=0$ and the problem
$$
au + (b + i\lambda)u_{xx} = 0, \ \  \text{in} \ \ (\alpha, \beta)
$$
with $0 < \alpha < \beta < \infty$.

I would like to know if the above problem has a solution. I know that the problem $au + (b + \lambda)u_{xx} = 0$ with the same conditions has a solution and is null.

I think in:
Let $V = (u,u_{x})^{T}$, then system can be written as the following

$$
V_{x} = BV, \ \ \text{with} \ \ V(\alpha) = 0
$$

with
$$ B = \left[
\begin{array}{cccc}
0 & 1 \\
-\frac{a}{ (b+i\lambda)}& 0 \\
\end{array}
\right] $$

The solution of the differential Equation is given by
$$
V(x) = e^{B(x - \alpha)}V(\alpha)
$$
Thus, the fact that $V(\alpha) = 0$, we get $V = 0$ in $(\alpha, \beta)$

I didn't use the fact that $u_{x}(\beta) = 0$.

**Am I right?**

Comment: There's always $u = 0$, but as far as nontrivial solutions, no, your system is overdetermined.

Comment: @Aruralreader I want to show that the solution is zero.

Comment: How is it overdetermined?

Comment: Too many boundary conditions.

Comment: @Aruralreader Yes, but I have this problem under these conditions and I want to show that the solution is null

Comment: @Aruralreader Regardless of the conditions, it is a problem to be solved.

Comment: @Aruralreader I'm asking if the way I solved it is right.

Comment: In that case what you want to do is prove uniqueness of solutions. You know $u = 0$ is one for sure, and if that's unique, you're done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fact that you didn't use $u_x(\beta) = 0$ is irrelevant, because it *is* true.

What you *have* shown is that the system *without* that condition is always zero. This solution satisfies $u_x(\beta) = c$ iff $c=0$, and so a condition with $c\neq 0$ gives no solution. Since your condition is not of this form, it doesn't contradict the solution not referencing it.

In terms of how you showed that, the method is correct.

Comment: Jone Thank you very much. I understood.